# PHPUnit's returnValueMap not yielding expected results

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I'm trying to use PHPUnit's [returnValueMap()](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) to stub out the results of a read.  It isn't yielding the expected results, but an equivalent returnCallback() does.  I've made my [test case](http://pastebin.com/xkRJdYfa) available if you'd like to inspect it yourself.

**returnValueMap()**

```
$enterprise = $this->getMock('Enterprise', array('field'));
$enterprise->expects($this->any())
    ->method('field')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap(array(
        array('subscription_id', null),
        array('name', 'Monday Farms')
    )));
$enterprise->subscribe('basic');
```

Results:

```
Subscription ID: NULL
Name: NULL
```

**returnCallback()**

```
$enterprise = $this->getMock('Enterprise', array('field'));
$enterprise->expects($this->any())
    ->method('field')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($arg) {
        $map = array(
            'subscription_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Monday Farms'
        );
        return $map[$arg];
    }));
$enterprise->subscribe('basic');
```

Results:

```
Subscription ID: NULL
Name: string(12) "Monday Farms"
```

**Enterprise::subscribe**

```
public function subscribe() {
    echo 'Subscription ID: ';
    var_dump($this->field('subscription_id'));
    echo 'Name: ';
    var_dump($this->field('name'));
}
```

Why doesn't returnValueMap() work as I expect it to?  What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I had the same problem and eventually found out that returnValueMap() has to map all parameters of your function, **including optional ones**, then the desired return value.

Example function from Zend Framework:

```
public function getParam($key, $default = null)
{
    $key = (string) $key;
    if (isset($this->_params[$key])) {
        return $this->_params[$key];
    }

    return $default;
}
```

Has to mapped like this:

```
$request->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getParam')
        ->will($this->returnValueMap(array(array($param, null, $value))));
```

Without the null in the middle, it won't work.

Comment: You just saved me **A LOT** of headaches. Thanks. PS: Kind of a shame that a lot of the quirks of PHPUnit are not in its official documentation....

Comment: Life saver! ther's also instances that the `null` needs to be `false` especially if `$param` (the key) is an integer

Answer (score 9):

I've been hunting down this same problem and eventually out of desperation xdebug-stepped through Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnValueMap.php and Framework/MockObject/InvocationMocker.php [in method InvocationMocker::invoke(PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation $invocation) ], and I've observed the following points:

1. Not only must the values in the map-array that you supply be the same as the expected parameters when the stubbed function is called, but they MUST BE OF THE SAME TYPE.  This is because inside Framework/MockObject/Stub/ReturnValueMap.php in the ReturnValueMap::invoke() method, the comparison between the supplied parameters and the expected parameters is compared in line 75 as follows:

   ```
   if ($invocation->parameters === $map) {
   ```

   So, the anticipated result of

   ```
   $mock->myStubbedMethod( "1", "2" )
   ```

   using a map-array of

   ```
   array(
       array( 1, 1, 500 ),
       array( 1, 2, 700 )
   )
   ```

   will disappoint.  Instead, the result will be a NULL.
2. On a much more subtle point, you may have stubbed the method using two different mock scenarios (as I did - yes, silly me!)

   So, to elucidate, the first mock-stub could contain

   ```
   $mock->expects( $this->any() )
          ->method('myStubbedMethod')
          ->will( $this->returnValue(750) );
   ```

   and then later, in the same unit-test method, it could contain

   ```
   $arrMap = array(
       array( 1, 1, 500 ),
       array( 1, 2, 700 ),
       array( 2, 3, 1500 ),
   );
   $mock->expects( $this->any() )
           ->method('myStubbedMethod')
           ->will( $this->returnValueMap($arrMap) );
   ```

   When the stubbed-method is invoked, the map-array version will be implemented.  This is obvious and self-evident, however while coding in the heat of the moment, and while separating different code behaviour in your mind as you develop, it's easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seems to lie either somewhere else in the code or might be an issue with an old PHPUnit version.

For me it works using this code:

**cat EnterpriseTest.php**

```
<?php

class EnterpriseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testReturnValueMap() {
        $enterprise = $this->getMock('Enterprise', array('field'));
        $enterprise->expects($this->any())
            ->method('field')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap(array(
                array('subscription_id', null),
                array('name', 'Monday Farms')
            )))
        ;
        $enterprise->subscribe('basic');        
    }

}

class Enterprise {

    public function field($name) {
    }

    public function subscribe() {
        echo 'Subscription ID: ';
        var_dump($this->field('subscription_id'));
        echo 'Name: ';
        var_dump($this->field('name'));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
phpunit-dev EnterpriseTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.Subscription ID: NULL
Name: string(12) "Monday Farms"


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

So while I can't tell why it doesn't work I can at least tell you that you are doing it right and that you've understood `returnValueMap` correctly :)