# PHPUnit Mock an object's properties

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I'm looking for a way to mock an object and populate its properties.
Here's an example of a method who uses a property of another object:

```
class MyClass {

    private $_object;

    public function methodUnderTest($object) {
        $this->_object = $object;
        return $this->_object->property
    }
}
```

To Unit Test this method I should create a mock of `$object` with the `getMockBuilder()` method from `PHPUnit`. But I can't find a way to mock the properties of the `$object`, just the methods.

Comment: Why don't you just set those properties without mocking them?

Comment: I actually tried to do that, but don't know why it never worked, until today.
Thanks for the heads up, you can actually set properties of mocked objects as you'd normally with an object

Comment: Luckily I'm not completely crazy, the simple solution you proposed works fine with most of my classes, but for a couple, it doesn't work and it just returns `NULL`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To add properties to a mocked object, you just set them as you'd normally do with an object:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')
             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
             ->getMock();

$mock->property = 'some_value';
```

`$mock->property` will now return `'some_value'`

Thanks to *akond*

P.s. for my project, this doesn't work with some classes, and when I try to call `$mock->property` it just returns `NULL`

Comment: Make sure you don't use magic methods inside the original class.

Comment: If your class uses magic methods you actually have to mock the `__get()` method and make it return the desired output. This was the reasons behind the failure in some of my classes

Comment: `disableOriginalConstructor()` needs parenthese to indicate it is a method, not a property. Otherwise you will get an error

Comment: @RiccardoCedrola how would you create such mocked `__get()` construct?

Comment: @powtac as you would normally do with any other method, you just mock the `__get()` and make it return the desired value. The problem is that this approach isn't really dynamic and it's hard to mock if is used multiple times inside the method you are testing. I might be wrong but I think there's a way where you mock a method by saying "when you receive A return B, when you receive X return Y"

Comment: If your class uses magic methods, you can mock __get for the specific property like this: `$mock->method('__get')->with('propname')->willReturn('fakevalue');`

Comment: @CollinKrawll This seems not to work when you need to mock __get for two or more different arguments?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Try PHPUnit's return value map: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482721/3649573

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `readonly` properties

Answer (score 27):

If you have classes with magic methods you can use:

```
$mock->method('__get')->with('property')->willReturn('value');
```

Comment: How would we deal with code that is getting multiple properties? I duplicated multiple lines for each property bu have an exception of `Expectation failed for method name is "__get"...`

Comment: This is also valid for private properties exposed by a publicmethod: $mock->method('publicmethod')->willReturn('value');